# mvc mini profiler - IIS7 issue

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, mvc-mini-profiler

similar to this question [mvc mini profiler (1.4) & IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555533/mvc-mini-profiler-1-4-iis)

I am running IIS 7.5 and my app pool is run in integrated mode on a Webforms site

and when the requests for the 
    mini-profiler-includes
files happen i get a bunch of 404 errors?

the only things i have changed are that i removed the MVChelpers folder and the MVC reference because we do not have them installed on our site.

It works fine from VS2010

Any ideas what I need to do to fix this?

THANKS

Comment: as a note from looking at other similar posts like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497180/mvcminiprofiler-results-request-giving-404-in-asp-net-mvc-app  i am wondering if it could be something in my global.asax.cs.. but there is nothing that clears out the route register?  I just have DefaultModel.RegisterContext(typeof(MyContext), new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = false });   and routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("{table}/{action}.aspx")
   {
    Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "List|Details|Edit|Insert" }),
    Model = DefaultModel
   });

Comment: my other thought would be that I need to add a <location> to my web.config but i tried that and it didnt seem to help?

Answer (score 5):

google knows all... sometimes i just need to dig a little deeper I suppose

anyway if you have this issue try adding this to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

worked for me.

Comment: Mini Profiler worked straight out of the box for one solution and not another. Turned out the another had an all-defaults web config that was missing this.

Comment: Great find. I had almost given up on MiniProfiler.