# Post to mini-profiler-results gives a 404 but only on live deployed site

Tags: http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvc-mini-profiler, web-config

I'm having some problems getting the POST results from MiniProfiler after the page has loaded.

I've tried a GET, and that works. But the POST returns a  404 error as if it were looking for a static file.

[image: shot of error]

*Any help or hints as to what I can try next would be much appreciated.*

Here's what I've looked at so far:

**It's Not My Routes**

The GET/POST issue would lead me to suspect a problem with my routes - except...

This problem only occurs on the live server. Locally, the routing runs fine.

**It Might be:  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequest?**

[Most things I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8011182/1778169) suggest setting this to true. However my problem seems to contradict this.

The problem occurs when `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequest="true"` set to true, and is fixed when set to false.  I would like to keep it set to true because I'm not knowlegable enough to change that from the default setting.

**Adding a Handler Didn't Help**

Other resources, [like this one (at the bottom of MP's home page)](http://miniprofiler.com/), suggest adding this line to system.webServer.handlers in web.config.

As I understand it, this should allow MP to run even if runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is set to false. For me, it has had no effect either way.

```
<add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

**But Could The handlers Section in Web.Config be Related?**

I have no particular reason to think it is...

I just don't fully understand what it's doing and wonder if this could account for the difference between local and deployed versions.

```
<handlers>

  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

    <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: I can't believe I'm having the same problem again, 3 years later. I was about to ask "did you ever solve this?" and realised that I was the OP.

Comment: so, did you ever solve this?

Comment: Afraid not. I have used MP since with no issues but on that project I never managed to get it working  :(

Comment: Did you try excluding that route in router config? `routes.IgnoreRoute("{*miniprofiler}", new { miniprofiler = @"(.*/)?mini-profiler-resources(/.*)?" });`. This worked for me in my project

Comment: Thanks Dominik. It was quite a while ago now, so I can't remember specifically.  But I don't think this was the issues in my case.  See "it's not my routes" above.